# Alternatives to Russell Bertrand's "History of Western Philosophy"

Tags: metaphilosophy

Do you know of any good alternatives to this book that give a wide representation of Western Philosophy?

Are there any good books that give a history of Eastern Philosophy?

Comment: Title: Connections to the world : the basic concepts of philosophy Author:  Danto, Arthur C., 1924-2013.   Publisher:University of California Press,Pub date:1997, c1989.  With Danto you also get someone who was keenly interested in art. Title: Encounters & reflections : art in the historical present, Author: Danto, Arthur C., 1924-2013.   Publisher:Farrar, Straus & Giroux,Pub date:c1990.  And other books. Mainly visual art. He wrote other

Comment: And Julian Marias, perhaps a bit dated now, but still good:  https://www.amazon.com/History-Philosophy-Historia-Filosofia-Julian/dp/0486217396  Also you can do a search here for other suggestions.

Comment: [Anthony Kenny's A New History](https://www.google.it/search?q=anthony+kenny+new+history&safe=active&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjikb3vzITbAhWHBZoKHaX5CK0Q_AUIECgB&biw=1366&bih=637).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any comprehensive histories of 'Eastern' philosophy but there are many surveys.

*Great Thinkers of the Eastern World* (Harper Collins) Ed. Ian P mcGreal.  This is very good. It leaves out far more great thinkers than it includes but this is inevitable.

For a compendium of ideas and extracts there is *A Treasury of Traditional Wisdom* (George, Allen & Unwin)

Evelyn Underhill's *Mysticism* is still popular but it is heavily coloured by Christian thinking and imho not well-informed or entirely trustworthy.

Huxley's *Perennial Philosophy* is still a good read although rather narrow imho.

Eagle Editions do a very good series called 'The Essence of...'that includes Gnosticism, Sufism, Rumi, Kabbala, Tao and other relevant topics.

*Hindu Scriptures* by RC Zachner is good and serves as a sort of ground-zero for the rest of the tradition.

There's a nice little book called *The Mystics of Islam* (Penguin) by Reynold Nicholson.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at *The Story of Philosophy* by Will Durant. First published in 1926, the popular history takes Western philosophy from Plato to Nietzsche, then discusses then-contemporary European philosophers Bergson, Croce, and Russell, and Americans Santayana, James and Dewey.

Answer (score 0):

For the western bit, try A New History of Western Philosophy by Anthony Kenny; there's also a history by Coppleston that is pretty good.